# Is there any mysql inbuilt function, through which we can subtract sum of different tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. tblPurchaseDetails as

```
SNO       ParticularID       Particular        Qty         Date
1            1                Apple             10           2019-01-01
2            2                Orange            20           2019-01-01
3            3                Papaya            10           2019-01-01
4            2                Orange            30           2019-01-04
5            1                Apple             50           2019-01-05
```

And another table tblStockoutdetails as

```
SNO       ParticularID       Particular        Qty         Date
1            1                Apple             10           2019-01-02
2            2                Orange            20           2019-01-02
4            2                Orange            10           2019-01-05
5            1                Apple             20           2019-01-06
```

Now I want to get current available stock of fruits, which should look like

```
ParticularID       Particular        Qty       
   1                Apple             30          
   2                Orange            20          
   3                Papaya            10
```

How to get this using mysql inbuilt function?
Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried

```
select purchasedetails.Particular, 
        sum(purchasedetails.qty)-sum(stockoutdetails.Qty) 
from purchasedetails 
    left join stockoutdetails on purchasedetails.particular=stockoutdetails.particular 
GROUP by purchasedetails.particular
```

Comment: Yes its called a query, have you tried to write one? If so show us

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes obviously I tried it. 
select purchasedetails.Particular, sum(purchasedetails.qty)-sum(stockoutdetails.Qty) from purchasedetails left join  stockoutdetails on  purchasedetails.particular=stockoutdetails.particular GROUP by purchasedetails.particular
But its now getting me the answer as expected.
Thanks

Comment: Then to be a good SO question you shoudl really show us, even if it is a failed attempt. That at least shows us where you are and gives us a little more context. It does not matter if its a failed attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want. It creates two derived tables of the SUMs of quantities from the purchase and stockout tables, and the takes the difference to get the onhand quantity:

```
SELECT p.ParticularID, p.Particular, COALESCE(p.Qty, 0) - COALESCE(s.Qty, 0) AS Qty
FROM (SELECT ParticularID, Particular, SUM(Qty) AS Qty
      FROM tblPurchaseDetails
      GROUP BY ParticularID, Particular) p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ParticularID, SUM(Qty) AS Qty
           FROM tblStockoutdetails
           GROUP BY ParticularID) s ON s.ParticularID = p.ParticularID
ORDER BY p.ParticularID
```

Output

```
ParticularID    Particular  Qty
1               Apple       30
2               Orange      20
3               Papaya      10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=69ada3d94c18ab920998ed3c19995f48)

Comment: Its a valid answer, and now the OP has posted their attempt its no longer a DIFM

Comment: Thank you so much It worked